# How to avoid syntax-highlighting for large files in vim?

Tags: vim, colors, vim-syntax-highlighting

Huge files take forever to load and work with in vim, due to syntax-highlighting.

I'm looking for a way to limit size of highlighted files, such that files larger than (say) 10MB will be colorless.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Adding the following line to _vimrc does the trick, with a bonus: it handles gzipped files, too (which is a common case with huge files):

```
autocmd BufWinEnter * if line2byte(line("$") + 1) > 1000000 | syntax clear | endif
```

Comment: You can probably keep your syntax highlighting if you just change `syntax clear` to `syn sync clear`.  It's the syncing that slows you down, although YMMV depending on the syntax involved.   Personally, I'm editing an 11 million line IDAPro .LST file with no issues after adding that line.

Comment: A tip I just discovered to greatly improve the loading time for huge files: disable folding if it has been defined, e.g. `set foldmethod=manual`.

Answer (score 16):

Add to your .vimrc:

```
autocmd BufReadPre * if getfsize(expand("%")) > 10000000 | syntax off | endif
```

Note that this disables syntax highlighting in ALL buffers; syntax is a global vim thing and cannot be restricted to a single buffer.

Comment: using 'syntax clear' instead of 'syntax off' applies to the one buffer only.

Answer (score 7):

I haven't tried it myself, but the [LargeFile](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1506) plugin seems to be exactly to address the kind of stuff you're looking for.

Answer (score 4):

vim -u NONE <filename>

This will skip all initializations from configuration files.

Use uppercase U when running gvim.

"-i NONE" does only exclude viminfo from being loaded. If you defined syntax hilighting in there, that would help too.

Answer (score 0):

vim -c 'syntax off' filename.ext

Comment: This will switch off highlighting _after_ loading the file.

Comment: `vim --cmd 'syntax off'` should run it *before* loading the file.